# Replacing string in list of non-empty strings

Tags: python, list

Trying to write code to replace/censor a word in a sentence/string. When I run it throws

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "python", line 21, in
>      File "python", line 10, in censor TypeError: list indices
>   must be integers, not str

Here's my code:

```
def censor(text, word):
    censored = text.split()
    censoredword ="*"*len(word)
    for n in censored:
        if n == word:
            censored[n] = censoredword

    print " ".join(censored)

censor("hey baby hey", "baby")
```

My expected output is `hey **** hey`

I've tested and printed replacing sections of the split string with `censored[1]= "string"`, printing output of `censoredword` for different `word` inputs, and I'm pretty sure I've iterated over a list in similar ways successfully, although not with replacing list items. I'm not trying to alter immutable strings in the list, simply replace a string in a list index with another. 
That said, testing this:

```
listbegin =['hey', 'baby', 'hey']
print " ".join(listbegin)
listbegin[1] = "*"*len(listbegin[1])
print " ".join(listbegin)
```

returns:

```
hey baby hey
hey **** hey
```

The exercise I'm attempting to do (self study, not homework) is assuming you don't know much more than what I've used - *I'm aware I can use `.append`, `.replace`, `index`, `enumerate`* etc, but I'd like to know why this code is throwing an error, since it seems it's component parts function fine.

What's obvious that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nonlinearfruit is correct. Your `for`...`in` is referring to the list items, not their index/position, so when you're going to replace, your statement `censored[n]` is referring to `censored[`hey`] or`censored[`baby]` rather than the position of those strings in the list, and as such it's throwing the error (because `hey` and `baby` are strings, not integers indicating their position in the list).

You can also condense your code by a line:

```
def censor(text, word):
    censored = text.split()
    for n in range(len(censored)): <== use `range()` 
        if censored[n] == word:
          censored[n] = "*"*len(word) <== 
    print " ".join(censored)
```

Answer (score 2):

A `for x in y` loop is a *for each* loop. `x` will take on the value of each element in `y`. So in this case, `x` will be a string and not the index. If you need the index, you need to iterate over the integers `0` to `len(censored)`:

```
for i in range(len(censored)):
    if censored[i] == word:
        censored[i] = censoredWord
```

Comment: Ah! I think I'd tried `in range` and `if censored[i]` but not both at the same time, cheers!

Comment: Actually, the `.replace` *is* helpful, if I wanted to do that I'd've been looking at a much longer function.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `n` is an element of list `censored`. So, `n` is a string. You can't use `n` as index. Only integers are allowed for indexing.

You can do following if you want to avoid too complex approach (avoinding enumerate and all that) -

```
i = 0
for n in censored:
    if n == word:
        censored[i] = censoredword
    i += 1
```

In this way you can keep track of the index